How to pull source codes from TFS for building images in openshift pipeline
I have created one openshift pipeline as follows:
- name: fetch-repository
  taskRef:
    kind: ClusterTask
    name: git-clone
  params:
    - name: URL
      value: $(params.git-url)
    - name: subdirectory
      value: ''
    - name: deleteExisting
      value: 'true'
    - name: revision
      value: $(params.git-revision)
    - name: sslVerify
      value: 'false'  # Disable SSL verification (temporary)
    - name: username
      valueFrom:
       secretKeyRef:
         name: git-secret
         key: username
    - name: password
      valueFrom:
       secretKeyRef:
         name: git-secret
         key: password
  workspaces:
    - name: output
      workspace: shared-workspace

Also created a secret as follows
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git-secret
  namespace: my-build-standalone
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
stringData:
  username: username
  password: password

But while saving the yaml in the openshift pipeline it shows valueFrom is an unknown field
An error occurred
admission webhook "webhook.pipeline.tekton.dev" denied the request: mutation failed: cannot decode incoming new object: json: unknown field "valueFrom"

any other possibilities to pull source code from TFS?

i have fixed this issue by adding the details in Task
main pipeline
   apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1
    kind: Pipeline
    metadata:
      name: build-and-deploy
      namespace: my-build-standalone
    spec:
      params:
        - default: ''
          description: Name of the deployment to be created
          name: deployment-name
          type: string
        - default: ''
          description: URL of the TFS repo for the code
          name: git-url
          type: string- default: master
          description: Revision to be used from the repo
          name: git-revision
          type: string
        - default: ''
          description: Image to be built and pushed
          name: IMAGE
          type: string
        - description: Previous image to roll back to (if required)
          name: previous-image
          type: string
      tasks:
        - name: fetch-repository
          params:
            - name: git-url
              value: $(params.git-url)
            - name: subdirectory
              value: ''
            - name: deleteExisting
              value: 'true'
            - name: git-revision
              value: $(params.git-revision)
            - name: sslVerify
             value: 'false'
          taskRef:
            kind: Task
            name: git-clone-with-auth
          workspaces:
            - name: output
              workspace: shared-workspace
        - name: build-image
          params:
            - name: IMAGE
              value: $(params.IMAGE)
          runAfter:
            - fetch-repository
          taskRef:
            kind: ClusterTask
            name: buildah
          workspaces:
            - name: source
              workspace: shared-workspace
      workspaces:
        - name: shared-workspace

created a task file as git-clone-with-auth
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: git-clone-with-auth
  namespace: my-build-standalone
  resourceVersion: '284080763'
  uid: 0cc45b5e-aabe-446f-baec-228fc362195e
spec:
  params:
    - name: git-url
      type: string
    - name: git-revision
      type: string
  steps:
    - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - |
          echo "Cloning repository..."
          git config --global credential.helper store
          git config --global http.sslVerify false
          set -e
          # Write credentials
          echo "https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@${FINAL_GIT_URL}" > ~/.git-credentials
          echo "Cloning repository ${GIT_URL} to ${WORKSPACE_PATH}..."
          git clone ${GIT_URL} ${WORKSPACE_PATH}
      computeResources: {}
      env:
        - name: GIT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: username
              name: git-secret
        - name: GIT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: git-secret
        - name: GIT_URL
          value: $(params.git-url)
        - name: WORKSPACE_PATH
          value: $(workspaces.output.path)
      image: alpine/git
      name: git-clone
  workspaces:
    - name: output

Now it's working as expected

After checking the document Specifying Parameters, it looks like the valueFrom field isn't supported when specifying parameters.
The valueFrom field can be used in the environment source. You can refer the example from Using a Secret as an environment source.
Sample:
env:
- name: GIT_USERNAME
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: git-secret
      key: username
- name: GIT_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: git-secret
      key: password


the same issue exists. unknown field "env"

env and params are at the same level of the task. Can you please share your updated yaml by edit your question?

fixed the issue by splitting the yaml using a task

Hi @Yaseen, glad to know that you have solved the issue! Thanks for sharing the answer.
